# Maven pom.xml dependencies - adjusting

Tags: java, maven

I am starting using Maven build tool for Java projects. I have added maven to system path and I have 3.5.3 version. I have to red tips in pom.xml file in Eclipse that something in this file is wrong. I tried to find some resources and I tried to change versions as in the source I used and next then build but it didn't work
I have such pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>authorization</groupId>
<artifactId>auth</artifactId>
<version>4.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>auth</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Maven build output errors:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for authorization:auth:4.1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter- 
parent:pom:3.5.3 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the 
local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update 
interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 
'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10
@ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project authorization:auth:4.1.0-SNAPSHOT 
(C:\Users\lukas\workspace\auth\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for authorization:auth:4.1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter- 
parent:pom:3.5.3 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the 
local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update 
interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 
'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10 -> [Help 
2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e 
switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please 
read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

I have checked **mvn -version** command and it is 3.5.3. The issue in my opinion is the SNAPSHOT statement. but how to adjust everything properly? I have used gradle and now I am doing maven.

Comment: I don't think you can write java version here (it's in your build) look [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Comment: The spring-boot-starter-parent version 3.5.3 does not exist. Either 2.0.2.RELEASE or 1.5.13.RELEASE If I correctly remember...

Answer (score 2):

Change your pom to :

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

If you check maven repo folder here https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/  you will see that the last version is 2.0.2.RELEASE

The version here is the version of the artifact that you want and not your Maven version (which is 3.5.3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pom.xml file,  and you won't face any issue, as I have tried and tested it out.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>authorization</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: There's still a problem in line: <parent> Multiple annotations found at this line. And the secound one is in line <project>